# How to create Keras Model() from VGG layers

Tags: python, keras, keras-layer, vgg-net

I have created a custom Keras model using the VGG16 base, which I train and save:

```
from keras.applications import VGG16
from keras import models
from keras import layers

conv_base = VGG16(weights="imagenet", include_top=False)

model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
...
model.save("models/custom_vgg16.h5")
```

In another script I now want to load that saved network and crete a new Keras `Model` object from it, using the custom networks input and the VGG16 layers as outputs:

```
from keras.models import load_model
from keras import Model

model_vgg16 = load_model("models/custom_vgg16.h5")

layer_outputs = [layer.output for layer in model_vgg16.get_layer("vgg16").layers[1:]]
activation_model = Model(inputs=model_vgg16.get_layer("vgg16").get_input_at(1), outputs=layer_outputs)
```

But the last line leads to the following error:

```
ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor Tensor("input_1:0", shape=(?, 150, 150, 3), dtype=float32) at layer "input_1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []
```

Any ideas what I might be missing here?

Comment: You probably want to get the input at node index 0 in the last line: `model_vgg16.get_layer('vgg16').get_input_at(0)`

Comment: @sdcbr Ohh dear, I was so focussed on the output layers, I have not even thought about that. Thanks a lot - you can write that as answer and I will gladly accept it.

Comment: alternative and equally functional: `model_vgg16.layers[0].input`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to get the input at node index 0 in the last line:

```
model_vgg16.get_layer('vgg16').get_input_at(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also get the input node by selecting the inputs directly from the model.

> model_vgg16.input

Answer (score 0):

you have to give input with respect to your image size
for example
if your image is of size 150,150,3 then try this

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(conv_base)
model.add(Input(shape=(150,150,3)))
model.add(layers.Flatten())
model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation="relu"))
model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
```